# Creating a Developer Profile

Tags: xcode, macos

How do you create a "DEVELOPER PROFILE" in xcode (4.2 on Snow Leopard)?
I accidentally deleted it from Keychain Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complete guide can be found here: [Developer Certificates and Provisioning Profiles](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Testing_iOS_5_Apps_on_the_iPhone_%E2%80%93_Developer_Certificates_and_Provisioning_Profiles)

Comment: Nope doesn't work.  I'm trying to recreate the developer profile not a new provisioning profile.

Answer (score 3):

My previous answer was focused towards a Mac developer as I didn't realize that there was a different page for iOS certificates etc.

Please try this link to obtain your [certificates](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action).

Comment: Nothing there, redirects me.  (I'm logged in and have a developer account)

Comment: @RobB That sounds bad.  What about from: https://developer.apple.com/certificates/index.action#overview

Comment: Same result. Running out of ideas!

Comment: @RobB I don't know what to say - you should see some certificates on the Apple Developer website.  I think you might need to contact them...

Comment: @RobB I have updated my answer; perhaps this one will finally help?

Comment: Yes I've always had access to that page. How can a certificate create a Developer Profile in xcode 4.2 though?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14706/discussion-between-rob-b-and-trojanfoe)

Comment: @RobB I have just recreated all my iOS Developer certificates from the page I linked to, and I did this by first revoking my Certificate and generating a new CSR and then updating all my profiles.  Once that is done you can then do a refresh from with Xcode (I use 4.4) and all is well.